# Add volume to SeaweedFS docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose, weed-fs, seaweedfs

I just working with `SeaweedFS` for a few days and I want to create `multiple master and volume and filer` in docker-compose so I just do that this way:

```
version: '2'

services:
  master_1:
    image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
    ports:
      - 9333:9333
      - 19333:19333
    command: "master -ip=master_1 -port=9333 -mdir=./1 -peers=master_1:9333,master_2:9334"

  master_2:
    image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
    ports:
      - 9334:9334
      - 19334:19334
    command: "master -ip=master_2 -port=9334 -mdir=./2 -peers=master_1:9333,master_2:9334"

  volume_1:
    image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 18080:18080
    command: 'volume -dir=./1 -port=8080 -mserver=master_1:9333,master_2:9334'
    depends_on:
      - master_1
      - master_2

  volume_2:
    image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
      - 18081:18081
    command: 'volume -dir=./2 -port=8081 -mserver=master_1:9333,master_2:9334'
    depends_on:
      - master_1
      - master_2

  filer:
    image: chrislusf/seaweedfs
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 18888:18888
    command: 'filer -master="master_1:9333,master_2:9334,master_3:9335"'
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - master_1
      - master_2
      - volume_1
      - volume_2
```

so in this `docker-compose.yml`, I want to create a docker volume so I can mount docker volume to my server disk for backup and safety. How can I found where the SeaweedFS uploaded files store in the docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are stored to where it is configured. In the above example, the data is under `./1` and `./2`, and filer is default to `./filerldb2`

BTW: The docker-compose file only has 2 masters. The filer is using 3 masters.